# why am I getting a NameError for authlogic method after upgrade to Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic, rails-3-upgrade

I am doing an upgrade to Rails 3 and had originally been using authlogic.

I now get a NameError:

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method `require_no_user'
```

'require_no_user" is a method for authlogic that is put into the UserSessions Controller.  But I'm getting an error and can't figure out why it is considered undefined.

I updated the authlogic gem to 3.0.3, but that hasn't fixed it.....

Yes, I will look into moving to Devise, but I really need to just get the basics of the upgrade done and hope I can do so...thanks.

Comment: Is the method exposed as a helper method in ApplicationController?

Comment: hmmm, no it's not, I assumed it was in the gem...I'll try adding it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. Unfortunaltely its not described in the tutorial. Here is the answer: https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic_example/blob/9b22672cd64fb31b405c000e207b2cae281baa58/app/controllers/application_controller.rb

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).